Count certain values between other values in column
I have the following very simplified situation in a table:
datetime id   event
-------- --   -----
dt01     67   1
dt02     67   2
dt03     106  1
dt04     106  4
dt05     106  2
dt06     654  1
dt07     654  4 
dt08     654  3
dt09     654  3
dt10     654  2
dt11     213  1
dt12     213  3
dt13     213  2
dt14     654  1
dt15     654  3
dt16     654  2

I want to count the number of 3's between the 1 and the 2.
The table is orderend on datetime and grouped by id (I can make it appear that way).
The answer is 0 for id 67, 0 for id 106, 2 for id 654, 1 for id 213 and (again!) 1 for id 654.
The 0's aren't important but ok if they show up in the result. I am looking for a result that has id 654 listed twice. I can not use the sum of the answers (3 in this case). It must be 2 and 1.
I have read several tickets on stackoverflow but I do not understand them (to be honest) or they are not applicable.
I might have overlooked possibilities with window functions but I did not see a solution.
I can imagine a solution using a stored procedure but I am not allowed to add a sp.

What do you want to calculate in terms of your table column names?

Do you really store dates in the form DTnn? And do you never have duplicate datetime? and is there always a 1..2 block or can you have 1 without 2? ie is the sample data representative?

Is there a possibility that a 3 is not "beween" a 1 and a 2? Can there be a 1 without a 2 or vice versa? Can the order be 2 .. 3 .. 1? If yes, what should be returned there? Are there situations where 1 and 2 are not the "first" resp "last" row of a block?

If the data looks like 13232 then the answer is 1 or 2? If the data looks like 1323132 then the answer is 2 or 3?

I want to count the 3's in the column 'event'.
No, real datetimes. I have simplified it here.
3's, 4's and other numbers are always between 1 (start) and 2 (end).
Data will never look like 13232.
I do not ask anyone to write 'the whole thing' for me. A SP is out of the question. I mention it as the route I can not take. I am simply on the search for a query that solves the issue, or hints to get me on the right track if possible.

Datetimes will never be duplicated for a given id.

Have you even tried anything???

@Eric. Yes I tried but got stuck. Now I am pointed at the real issue (a gaps and islands problem). Knowing that and with the help in this ticket I will try again.
As I wrote earlier, I simplified the situation for the question. I have to translate the solution to the real table. Thanks everyone for the discussion.

So what to help if there is no query???

For example, this can be
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM table
JOIN ( SELECT id, 
              MIN(CASE WHEN event = 1 THEN datetime END) mindatetime, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN event = 2 THEN datetime END) maxdatetime
       FROM table
       WHERE event IN (1, 2)
       GROUP BY 1
       ) subquery USING (id)
WHERE table.datetime BETWEEN subquery.mindatetime AND subquery.maxdatetime
  AND table.event = 3
GROUP BY 1;

https://dbfiddle.uk/hSxExR3P

Thank you. I see and understand why this works. I will try your solution on the actual case as soon as I find the time. I will vote your solution.

This does not produce the result the OP asked for ' I am looking for a result that has id 654 listed twice...It must be 2 and 1.'

@P.Salmon There are 2 adjacent rows for id=654, with dt=6..10 and 14..16. If OP needs to count these ranges separately then he must enumerate adjacent rows and use this number as additional grouping factor.

Since there are multiple groups of rows for the same id you should flag the first row of each group and then populate the flag to the rest of the group.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE tbl (datetime CHAR(4), id INT, event INT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('dt01',      67,  1),
('dt02',      67,  2),
('dt03',     106,  1),
('dt04',     106,  4),
('dt05',     106,  2),
('dt06',     654,  1),
('dt07',     654,  4),
('dt08',     654,  3),
('dt09',     654,  3),
('dt10',     654,  2),
('dt11',     213,  1),
('dt12',     213,  3),
('dt13',     213,  2),
('dt14',     654,  1),
('dt15',     654,  3),
('dt16',     654,  2);

... the grid cte flags the first row of each group of id rows ...
WITH 
    grid AS
      ( Select     datetime, id, event,
                   Case When id != Coalesce(LAG(id) Over(Order By datetime ), 'dt00')
                        Then datetime
                   End as grp
        From       tbl
        Where      event < 4
      )

... the inner query populates the group flag to the reamining rows of the same group and outer query aggregates the data conditionaly grouping them by grp, id ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT    id, Count(Case When event = 3 Then 1 End) as cnt
FROM    ( Select     datetime, id, event, 
                     Max(grp) 
                         Over( Order By datetime 
                               Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row ) as grp
          From       grid
          Order By   datetime
        ) x
GROUP BY    grp, id
HAVING      Min(event) = 1  And 
            Max(Case When event != 3 Then event End) = 2
ORDER BY    grp, id 

... having clause should exclude the groups that doesn't containe events 1 and/or 2 ...
/*
 id  cnt
---  ---
 67    0
106    0
654    2
213    1
654    1    */

If the event 3 should be between 1 and 2 (ordered by datetime) then the HAVING clause should be changed into:
... ...
HAVING    ( Min(Case When event = 1 Then datetime End) < Min(Case When event = 3 Then datetime End) And 
            Max(Case When event = 2 Then datetime End) > Min(Case When event = 3 Then datetime End) 
          ) OR Count(Case When event = 3 Then 1 End) = 0
... ...

... the result is the same as above ...
See the fiddle here.

This is called a gaps and islands problem. You want to consider adjacent rows of the same ID a group. One simple way to achieve this is to create group keys by subtracting an ID row number from a total row number. Once you have the groups, you can count conditionally. In MySQL the simplest way of doing this is to SUM the expression, because true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL.
with
  grouped as
  (
    select 
      datetime, id, event,
      row_number() over (order by datetime)-
      row_number() over (partition by id order by datetime)
        as subid
    from mytabe
  )
select id, sum(event = 3)
from grouped
group by id, subid
order by min(datetime);

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fGzDmDIm

It is possible to approach your question as a problem  gaps and islands.
Rows with event=1 - start island group. event=2 - end of island.
Then set island(group) num as running total of group edges.
I will use different mark for start and end of island to separate islands, not like (1....2).
To count event=3 we use group_concat for events in(1,2,3). Group string is like 1....2.
See examples:

If your data strictly have sequence (1,....,2) query may be simple

select id,sum(case when event=3 then 1 else 0 end)cnt
from (
  select *,sum(case when event=1 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by datetime) grn
  from test
)y
group by grn,id

Or
select  id
    ,length(group_concat(case when event in (1,2,3) then event end 
              order by datetime separator ''))-2 cnt
from (
   select *
     ,sum(case when event=1 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by datetime) grn
   from test
 )y
group by grn,id


With more checks for event sequence

select id, case when grs like '1%2' then length(grs)-2 end cnt ,grn, grs
from(
  select id,grn
    ,group_concat(case when event in (1,2,3) then event end 
                  order by datetime separator '') grs
  from (
     select * ,sum(isGap)over(order by datetime) grn
     from(
      select *
       ,case when event=1 then 1 
         when lag(event)over(order by datetime)=2 then 2
        else 0
        end isGap
      from test
   ) x
  )y
  group by grn,id
)z





id
cnt
grn
grs




67
0
1
12


106
0
2
12


654
2
3
1332


213
1
4
132


654
1
5
132



Details for gaps and islands:
select *
  ,sum(isGap)over(order by datetime) grn
from(
select *
  ,case when event=1 then 1 
     when lag(event)over(order by datetime)=2 then 2
   else 0
   end isGap
from test
) x




datetime
id
event
isGap
grn




dt01
67
1
1
1


dt02
67
2
0
1


dt03
106
1
1
2


dt04
106
4
0
2


dt05
106
2
0
2


dt06
654
1
1
3


dt07
654
4
0
3


dt08
654
3
0
3


dt09
654
3
0
3


dt10
654
2
0
3


dt11
213
1
1
4


dt12
213
3
0
4


dt13
213
2
0
4


dt14
654
1
1
5


dt15
654
3
0
5


dt16
654
2
0
5



fiddle
